# Why does the following URL return $santize:badparse

Tags: angularjs

I need to fire an ng-click when I bind the following

```
<a href='#' ng-click ='GotoUrl('www.cnn.com')'>CNN</a>
```

I get $santize:badparse

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "< href='#' ng-click='GotoUrl('www.cnn.com')'>CNN<a>"

Comment: You are using single quotes for the attribute value delimiter as well as the string.  Escape them or switch the one of the sets of quotes to double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/08k1ztsa/1/

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.GotoUrl = function(url){
            window.open(url);
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
        <a href='#' ng-click ='GotoUrl("http://www.cnn.com")'>CNN</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used nested quotes. Try this:

```
<a href='#' ng-click ='GotoUrl("www.cnn.com")'>CNN</a>
```